# Как выбрать все поля из связанной таблицы одним запросом?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы: в одной проекты, а в другой ключевые слова к ним. Этот запрос забирает данные сразу из двух таблиц:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pos_projects 
  JOIN pos_keywords ON pos_projects.id = pos_keywords.pid 
WHERE pos_projects.userid= :userid 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Но из второй таблицы он забирает только одну строку, а как забрать все?

Comment: убрать `WHERE pos_projects.userid= :userid`

Comment: Это необходимость. Мне надо выбрать проекты только конкретного юзера. И `pos_projects` - это первая таблица, мне надо из нее забрать все проекты, и из второй (`pos_keywords`) забрать все строки к каждому проекту

Comment: Ну, значит, у этого юзера только один проект.

Comment: Добавьте проблемные данные в вопрос. Пока желаемое вами поведение совпадает с структурой запроса.

Comment: Нет, их три. И у каждого проекта во второй таблице несколько ключей

Comment: @4per, [Скриншот 1](http://imghost.in/img/2016-10/11/skjugfwq4bfnmj5o2gpt05eva.png) | [Скриншот 2](http://imghost.in/img/2016-10/11/u5xgwz76kda8t49zhl9bz1hfk.png) | [Скриншот 3](http://imghost.in/img/2016-10/11/h0o409xfj6gefjfc40ashmrib.png)

Comment: Хмм, может попробовать использовать `LEFT JOIN` ?

Comment: Судя по картинкам вы в свой массив прочитали только одну строку. прочитайте все строки.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` прочитать проекты помог, но из второй таблицы по прежнему забирается только один keyword. Надо чтобы все

Comment: Может `CROSS JOIN`?

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky♦, почему sql-запрос в одну строку? читать вопрос от этого легче не стало.

Comment: @4per Он такой, каким его написал автор вопроса. Если вы считаете, что он должен выглядеть иначе, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку! Внес изменения, если что–то не так, пишите, улучшим вместе!

Answer (score 2):

Как пример (альтернатива) - есть города (cities) и страны (countries), у города есть countryId = countries.id.
Чтобы выбрать все города для конкретной страны, я пишу:

```
SELECT countries.name, cities.name FROM countries join cities on countries.id = cities.countryId where countries.name = 'Испания';
```

Мне выдается два столбца - первый это название страны, второй - города.

У вас он возвращает все данные из проектов, но ничего из слов (т.к. написано  select * from pos_projects, и всё)